# Passing horizontal scrolling down to a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I've got a UICollectionView with a horizontally left-to-right scrolling flow layout. Each cell is the size of the whole screen.

I want to be able to overlay a UIScrollView (possibly a UITableView), which scrolls vertically up and down over the screen as well.

So my question is, how do I pass left-right scrolls down to the UICollectionView, as use up-done scrolls on the uppermost scrollview?

```
        |         |
        |         |
       -------------
-------|-----------|-------------
       ||         ||
       ||         ||         <  >
       ||         ||   Collection View  
       ||         ||
       ||         ||
       ||         ||
-------|-----------|-------------
       -------------
        |         |
        | ^Scroll |
        | ∨ View  |
        |         |
```

Comment: Have you tried? There's nothing (programmatically) I can see that is in your way, just create a custom CollectionViewCell class and add your scrollView or tableView to it.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I thought that there might be a conflict with the scroll directions, or that adding a table to collection view cell might be too 'heavy', but it seems to work.